# ssh-add -D deletes keys on originating host

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have an ssh-agent running on my macbook. I use ssh -A and carry the keys forward to my redhat box.

The thing that surprises me though is that when I do a 'ssh-add -D' on the redhat box, the keys not only disappear locally but they also get removed on my macbook. How does that work?

Seems like there is some pipe open all the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ssh-add connect to running agent through Unix domain sockets. SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable holds the path of the socket. ssh-add checks the variable and connects to the agent who is reachable via the socket, not the one running locally.

When you ssh into a machine with -o ForwardAgent=yes set  the above variable is set to point to a socket which is connected to the agent running in the origin host.

If you want ssh-add connect to the agent running locally, point the above variable to the path of the socket which is being listened by local agent. you can get the local agnets socket by `sudo lsof -p $(pgrep ssh-agent)` and look for a file in /tmp of type socket.